# user defined function in insert command

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I created a function:

```
DELIMITER $$  

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `heena`.`customer_id`$$ 

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION  `heena`.`customer_id`(
  a varchar(20),
  b varchar(20)
) RETURNS varchar(50) CHARSET latin1     
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN       
   RETURN CONCAT(
            (select ((id), 0) + 1
             from heenaj),
             substring(a,1,2),
             substring(b,1,2));  
END;$$  

DELIMITER ;
```

The code executed fine, but when I'm inserting a value using:

```
insert into heenaj
   (c_id,name,number)
values
   (customer_id121("abcd",9868275817),"abcd",9868275817);
```

It shows an error:

> Column 'c_id' cannot be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something wrong with your `RETURN`.

Maybe you are meaning to do this, although I am only guessing:

```
RETURN CONCAT(
            (select ifnull(max(id), 0) + 1
             from heenaj),
             substring(a,1,2),
             substring(b,1,2));
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/720eb0/1)

Then, you're calling `customerid121()` not `customer_id()`. Could this be typo?

Also, in looking at what you're trying to do: do you want your `id` as `auto_increment` and just want to have `c_id` as the `id`, concatenated with first 2 characters of `name` and concatenated with first 2 characters of `number`?

I suggest another solution. It might be nicer to drop your function and create a `TRIGGER` for before `INSERT`, like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_customer_id BEFORE INSERT on heenaj
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.c_id = CONCAT((SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id),0)+1 FROM heenaj),SUBSTRING(NEW.name,1,2),SUBSTRING(NEW.number,1,2));
END/
```

This way, when you insert you can just ignore `c_id` and insert like this:

```
insert into heenaj(name,number)
values ("abcd",9868);
```

The trigger will handle the setting of `c_id` for you.
[sqlfiddle for TRIGGER](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4904c/1)

P.S. To create the trigger (in the sqlfiddle), I selected `/` as my delimiter. You might change that `/` to `$$`, since you're setting delimiter as `$$`.

Comment: yes thank you so much for you help. :)It really helped